# How to set maven pom file to a bintray version?

Tags: maven, bintray

One of my project's dependencies is in the bintray under the link

```
https://bintray.com/azavea/geotrellis/geotrellis-spark/view
```

And they have given maven snippet as below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azavea.geotrellis</groupId>
  <artifactId>geotrellis-spark_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>0.10.0-a9ab100</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Can i just use it in the POM file of my maven project, or do I have to add anything in the `<repository></repository>` to configure a repository to download this dependency from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure Maven to use Geotrellis repository. In short, you need to add it to Maven's `settings.xml` file.

Please click on the Set Me Up button on [the repo page](https://bintray.com/azavea/geotrellis) and follow the instructions under section "Resolving artifacts using Maven".

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to desired Bintray project/repository (example https://bintray.com/jerady/maven/FontAwesomeFX/11.0.0)
2. Click **SET ME UP!** icon (upper right corner)[image]
3. Click **Download Settings** in Popup [image]
4. Save settings into your Maven user directory (example C:\Users\myusername.m2)
5. Add dependency into your POM.xml file as usual

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this artifact is in the [Maven central repo](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/azavea/geotrellis/geotrellis-spark_2.10/), but the only published version there is: `0.10.0-M1`.

My guess is that using this version in your project's `pom.xml` dependency snippet should be okay.

If you want to actually use the exact same version `0.10.0-a9ab100`, then you could download the `JAR` file from `bintray` and use the `Maven install plugin` (`mvn install:install-file` or something similar) to install it in the local repository (`~/.m2`).

Comment: This is an **absolutely** wrong answer. Please delete it ASAP.

Comment: @JBaruch I am not sure what is wrong in *what I wrote*. Care to explain?

Comment: Downloading the file manually and deploying into local repository with `mvn install` is a completely wrong way to use Bintray. Bintray fully supports Maven.

Comment: Downloading bintray? I never suggested that. I was just suggesting installing a particular dependency manually. In general, being able to install a dependency to a local repo to get your build going is pretty handy while using Maven. I am not sure why you (seem to have) downvoted this answer.

Comment: You wrote "you should download the JAR file from bintray" so you did suggest it.
I downvoted the answer because downloading the file manually from Bintray and installing it manually into your local cache is a completly wrong way to use Bintray. Please see my answer for the correct way of doing what @vds asked about.

Comment: OK, I edited a bit (should -> could) to reflect my intent. I can live with the downvote because I can see the confusion it can cause in a reader's mind, however I believe that reader might just get the _spirit_ of what I am trying to say.

Comment: WHY? Why someone would want to manually download and install an artifact when they just can use Maven dependency management?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106028/discussion-between-kedar-mhaswade-and-jbaruch).